# Run anacron even when on battery (laptop)

Tags: 11.10, laptop, power-management, cron

There is a known behavior of anacron not to run when the laptop is running on batteries. Is there any way to stop this behavior and run anacron whatever the power state?

http://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=152402

http://www.mail-archive.com/debian-bugs-dist@lists.debian.org/msg560900.html

https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/anacron/+bug/36816

Comment: Are you sure it's up to anacron ? cron.daily/apt, cron.daily/mlocate and cron.daily/apt-xapian-index do call /usr/bin/on_ac_power explicitly to check whether the script is being run on a battery. You could probably just comment these conditions within those scripts as a solution.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Please *never* change any files in `/usr`!  Instead, you may change a line in the file `/etc/default/anacron` to

`ANACRON_RUN_ON_BATTERY_POWER=yes`

Thanks @Teresa e Junior. :)

Comment: Only works when not running systemd. Otherwise look at /usr/share/doc/anacron/README.Debian for instructions on creating /etc/systemd/system/anacron.service.d/on-ac.conf. The README tell what contents the file should be created with. This worked for me running daily snapshots with rsnapshot. I Have only tried this on Ubuntu 20.04, so not sure if it will work for other distros using systemd and not Debian based. This answer lead me to solving the issue for myself though ...thanks so much : )

Answer (score 1):

I found how to do this and summarized it in my blogpost

http://opensourceresearchtips.blogspot.com/2012/01/linux-anacron-tips.html

To change this behavior of anacron do the following:

```
 sudo gedit /usr/lib/pm-utils/power.d/anacron
```

and change to

```
case $1 in
    false)
 start -q anacron || :
 ;;
    true)
 start -q anacron || :
 ;;
esac
```

Comment: Just edit `/etc/default/anacron`, and set `ANACRON_RUN_ON_BATTERY_POWER` to *yes*. You should never edit files in `/usr`.

Comment: you may want to change this comment to an answer

Answer (score 1):

For Debian based systems using systemd look at `/usr/share/doc/anacron/README.Debian` for instructions on creating `/etc/systemd/system/anacron.service.d/on-ac.conf`. The README tells what contents the file should be created with. This worked for me running daily snapshots with rsnapshot. I Have only tried this on Ubuntu 20.04. It seems likely that other distros may have a similar README in that directory. `/etc/default/anacron` has instructions to look in `/usr/share/doc/anacron/README.Debian` in Ubuntu 20.04. Thanks so much @mzuther : )

Just in case the README is not on someone's system the file contents should be:

```
[Unit]
ConditionACPower=
```