# /etc/systemd/system/anacron.service.d missing

Tags: battery, systemd, anacron

I'm using Lubuntu LTS 20.04.3 and I'm an unexperienced user. I'm trying to set my `anacron` service running on battery, since by default it only runs when on AC power. I'm running on `systemd` and I thoroughly read both the `anacron man` and `/usr/share/doc/anacron/README.Debian`. It is said that in order to enable anacron running on battery in a `systemd` environment I should create this file `/etc/systemd/system/anacron.service.d/on-ac.conf`. Now, the issue is that `anacron.service.d` doesn't exist, nor any other anacron related directory. I'm sure it's a stupid question, but I'd be extremely grateful if anybody could help me with that.

Comment: You can likely just create the directory yourself - afaik, files (and directories) in `/etc/systemd` are for "local" overrides of the defaults in `/etc/systemd/system/` so don't necessarily exist (but should be read and processed if they do).

Comment: Thank you so much! I actually thought of doing it, but I was afraid I could "mess up" things.

Comment: Can you confirm whether it actually works? The solution was posted previously [here](https://askubuntu.com/a/1313639/178692) but received 0 upvotes. If it works we should probably upvote that and close this as a duplicate.

Comment: Is there a way I can run anacron immediately, to see if it works on battery? I'm currently waiting for my next scheduled job to run, to see if it works and get back to you.

Comment: No rush - it would just be nice to know ;)

Comment: I'm back, thank you again, it works!